# Angular 6 Dynamic module loading

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I want to load a module dynamically. I have a file 'profile.module.js'.

working codebase.

```
  addModule() {
  System.import('./profile.module.js').then((module) => {
    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module.ProfileModule)
      .then((compiled) => {
        const factory = compiled.componentFactories[0];
        this._container.createComponent(factory);
      });
  });
```

}

In the above example, I have given a static module path './profile.module.js'. It is working fine.
but if I pass path dynamically then it will give me an error.

```
url = './profile.module.js';
  addModule() {
  System.import(this.url).then((module) => {
    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module.ProfileModule)
      .then((compiled) => {
        const factory = compiled.componentFactories[0];
        this._container.createComponent(factory);
      });
  });
```

}

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './profile.module.js'
Error: Cannot find module './profile.module.js'

Comment: this is my working repo - https://github.com/DatsGawas/module-loader.git